# In a glass of water, will an ice cube ever touch the bottom?

Tags: water, density

No matter the mass of the ice cube or the level of the water, will the ice cube ever touch the bottom of the glass or will there always be a layer of water in between?

Comment: Think of the limiting case when there is no liquid water.  Clearly the ice would be resting on the bottom of the container, assuming it is cold enough for the water to be ice at that pressure.

Answer (score 3):

Well if you put an ice cube into an empty glass, most people would say it is touching the bottom (big glass).   The nit pickers may claim there is a melted layer of water in between.   But this glass has been chilled to -10 deg C first.

So yes; the ice cube can touch the bottom.

Now if I add water, the cube will not float until 9/10 or 10/11 or so of the cube is under water.

So most likely, the ice cube will touch the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

The ice cube needs to displace an amount of water with mass equal to its weight (units aside). If you put an ice cube on the bottom of a bathtub, and fill the bathtub with 1mm of water (imagine a perfectly level bathtub), keeping your hand firmly pressed on the ice cube, what do you suppose is the amount of water the ice cube is displacing in this state? Does it weigh as much as an ice cube does?

The corollary is that if you can make the water level go up high enough, then you can support any mass (provided that it is buoyant) with relatively little fluid (think a cargo ship in a bucket of water, practicality aside).